# Liquibase Code generated for a conditional index gives error in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, liquibase, filtered-index

I have this following index in my SQL Server Database

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XCR_ACTIVE ON dbo.CS_PA_VEH_BASE ( ETL_ACTIVE_FL )
WHERE ETL_ACTIVE_FL = 'N' ON "default";
```

for which `liquibase` gives out following:

```xml
<createIndex indexName="XCR_ACTIVE" tableName="CS_PA_VEH_DELTA">
    <column computed="true" name="([ETL_ACTIVE_FL]='N')"/>
</createIndex>
```

But when I want to execute it (also in MS SQL Server) I get the following

```
> **Error:**  (14.2) 05-24-19 11:43:05 (E) (13004:15088) RUN-050304: |Session JOB_ODS_Liquibase Function call <raise_exception ( Liquibase
> update error: 1: Unexpected error running Liquibase: Incorrect syntax
> near '('. [Failed SQL: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XCR_ACTIVE ON
> [dbo].[CS_PA_VEH_DELTA](([ETL_ACTIVE_FL]='N'))] ) > failed, due to
> error <50316>: <Liquibase update error:-1: Unexpected error running
> Liquibase: Incorrect syntax near '('. [Failed SQL: CREATE NONCLUSTERED
> INDEX XCR_ACTIVE ON [dbo].[CS_PA_VEH_DELTA](([ETL_ACTIVE_FL]='N'))]>.
```

I hope it's not the first time this is happening to someone.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56339141/2788085), there is no support for partial/conditional/filtered indexes in Liquibase.

What you tried to do, is to use `computed` attribute to set a condition for filter. [Documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/create-index.html) for computed states:

> The attribute to set to true if the value in name isn't actually a
> column name but a function. Boolean.

So, it is only used if you want to programmatically name the column to be indexed. So you either have to use `pure SQL` or `modifySql`.

---

### modifySql

With `modifySql` you can append sql before or after generated statements, or replace parts of it. If we try with append it would look like this:

```xml
<changeSet id="create-an-index-modifySql" author="potato">
    <createIndex tableName="CS_PA_VEH_BASE"
                 indexName="XCR_ACTIVE"
                 clustered="false">
       <column name=ETL_ACTIVE_FL>
    </createIndex>
    <modifySql>
        <append value="WHERE ETL_ACTIVE_FL = 'N'">
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

Which will produce following sql statement:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XCR_ACTIVE ON CS_PA_VEH_BASE ( ETL_ACTIVE_FL )
WHERE ETL_ACTIVE_FL = 'N';
```

The issue with this approach is when using `tablespace` attribute; `WHERE` will be appended after `ON tablespace`. Example:

```xml
<changeSet id="create-an-index-modifySql" author="potato">
    <createIndex tableName="CS_PA_VEH_BASE"
                 indexName="XCR_ACTIVE"
                 tablespace="default"
                 clustered="false">
       <column name=ETL_ACTIVE_FL>
    </createIndex>
    <modifySql>
        <append value="WHERE ETL_ACTIVE_FL = 'N'">
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XCR_ACTIVE ON CS_PA_VEH_BASE ( ETL_ACTIVE_FL )
ON default WHERE ETL_ACTIVE_FL = 'N';
```

which has wrong syntax.

The solution would be to use `modifySql` with `replace` and `with` attributes:

```xml
<changeSet id="create-an-index-modifySql" author="potato">
    <createIndex tableName="CS_PA_VEH_BASE"
                 indexName="XCR_ACTIVE"
                 tablespace="default"
                 clustered="false">
       <column name=ETL_ACTIVE_FL>
    </createIndex>
    <modifySql>
        <append replace="ON default" with="WHERE ETL_ACTIVE_FL = 'N' ON default">
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XCR_ACTIVE ON CS_PA_VEH_BASE ( ETL_ACTIVE_FL )
WHERE ETL_ACTIVE_FL = 'N' ON default;
```

Although correct, I consider it too fiddly and error prone.

---

### Pure SQL

The safest bet would be to create a `changeSet` with `sql` tag, something like this:

```xml
<changeSet id="create-an-index-pure-sql" author="potato">    
    <sql>
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XCR_ACTIVE
            ON dbo.CS_PA_VEH_BASE (ETL_ACTIVE_FL)
        WHERE ETL_ACTIVE_FL = 'N' ON "default";
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Although it is not in the spirit of Liquibase, I consider it good enough solution for filtered indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is mentioned about "Indexes with Filter" in the standard Liquibase documentation:
https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_index.html
but what Nathan mentions here http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/how-to-create-conditional-indexes-using-createindex?reply=true about modifySQL should work.